# How do i calculate $\sin^2(90)/\cos(90)$? It should be around -1.

Tags: trigonometry

I need help to understand why $\sin(90)^2/\cos(90)$ is around $-1.78370251173...$

Comment: What is in radians?

Comment: Do you not know what radians are, or are you asking what it would be in radians?

Comment: I know what are radians but i still dont understand you.

Comment: Why do you say it should be around $-1$ in the title, when you indicate otherwise in the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $90$ denotes *radians*, $\sin(90)\approx0.8939966636$ and $\cos(90)\approx-0.4480736161$, in which case

$${\sin^2(90)\over\cos(90)}\approx{(0.8939966636)^2\over-0.4480736161}\approx-1.7837025117$$

If the $90$ were intended as *degrees*, then $\sin(90^\circ)=1$ while $\cos(90^\circ)=0$, in which case $\sin^2(90^\circ)/\cos(90^\circ)$ would be *undefined*.

Remark: $90$ radians is not quite fourteen and a third times around the circle (i.e., $90/(2\pi)=14.3239448783\ldots\lt14.3333333\ldots$), which explains why $\sin(90)$ is somewhat larger than $\sqrt3/2=0.8660254038\ldots$ and $\cos(90)$ is somewhat less than $-1/2=-0.500000000$.

Comment: +1 for the insightful remark

Comment: Thanks for the help.